# Build triple UNION query using Arel (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, arel

`user has_many tasks`

I'm trying to create a 3 select UNION:

```rb
Task.from("(#{select1.to_sql} UNION #{select2.to_sql} UNION #{select3.to_sql}) AS tasks")
```

But with Arel.

I can easily use Arel for UNION query for 2 selects:

```rb
tasks_t = Task.arel_table
select1 = tasks_t.project('id').where(tasks_t[:id].eq(1)) # SELECT id FROM tasks WHERE tasks.id = 1
select2 = Task.joins(:user).select(:id).where(users: {id: 15}).arel  # SELECT "tasks".id FROM "tasks" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "tasks"."user_id" WHERE "users"."id" = 15
union = select1.union(select2) # SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id = 1 UNION SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id = 2

union_with_table_alias = tasks_t.create_table_alias(union, tasks_t.name)
Task.from(union_with_table_alias)
# SELECT "tasks".* FROM ( SELECT id FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."id" = 1 UNION SELECT "tasks"."id" FROM "tasks" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "tasks"."user_id" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ) "tasks"  [["id", 15]]

#=> Task::ActiveRecord_Relation [#<Task: id: 1>, #<Task: id: 2>]
```

How can I do it with triple union select?

```rb
select3 = tasks_t.project('id').where(tasks_t[:id].eq(3)) # SELECT id FROM tasks WHERE tasks.id = 3
```

Something like:

```rb
triple_union = select1.union(select2).union(select3)
triple_union_with_table_alias = tasks_t.create_table_alias(triple_union, tasks_t.name)
Task.from(triple_union_with_table_alias)
```

Which should roughly translate to

```rb
Task.from("(#{select1.to_sql} UNION #{select2.to_sql} UNION #{select3.to_sql}) AS tasks")
```

Note the above line also fails:
`Caused by PG::ProtocolViolation: ERROR:  bind message supplies 0 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 1`

To summarize:
How to use `Arel` to build a tripple UNION query? `select 1 UNION select 2 UNION select 3`

Thank you

`Ruby 2.5.3` `Rails 5.2.4` `Arel 9.0.0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not invoke `union` in an `Arel::Nodes::Union`, because in the method definition the `ast` of both objects is called. And the result of a `union` operation doesn't respond to `ast`:

```
def union(operation, other = nil)
  if other
    node_class = Nodes.const_get("Union#{operation.to_s.capitalize}")
  else
    other = operation
    node_class = Nodes::Union
  end

  node_class.new(self.ast, other.ast)
end
```

What you can do is to manually call Arel::Nodes::Union, passing as any of those arguments the result of a union:

```
Arel::Nodes::Union.new(Arel::Nodes::Union.new(select1, select2), select3)
```

Comment: 1 gotcha- this will only work (for me at least) with Arel objects- not AR- so for the select2 in my example - which is created through AR- need to call `arel` on it so `Task.joins(...).arel` to convert from AR object to Arel `select_manager` object

Comment: That's because without invoking `arel` on `select2`, it is a pure `Task::ActiveRecord_Relation`, nothing to do with Arel. You must create a pure `Arel::SelectManager` for that. Try `users_t = User.arel_table; Arel::Nodes::Union.new(
  Arel::Nodes::Union.new(
    tasks_t.project('id').where(tasks_t[:id].eq(1)),
    tasks_t.project('id').where(tasks_t[:id].eq(3))
  ),
  tasks_t.join(users_t).on(users_t[:id].eq(tasks_t[:user_id])).project('id').where(users_t[:id].eq(15))
)`.